# How to update class object attributes in Tkinter Labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to make a Team ranking tool in python. I made a team class with different attributes that influence a strength attribute. I wanted to list the teams graphically with tkinter in order from highest strength to lowest strength, even when I change around some team's attributes. I used Labels with the team's name, rank, and strength as the text. I wanted these Labels to update when I changed the name or strength of the team. It currently does not update when I add team attributes to the GUI. As I am still a beginner in Tkinter and Python in general, I would like to know what is wrong with my code and how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
# Graphical configuration
root = Tk()
root.title('Robot scouting software\u00A9')
teamtype = 'Competition home'



if teamlisted == need:
    team = Teamsort()

#Competition homepage

g = StringVar()
#Rank Labels
ordinals = ['st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th']
for x in range(0, len(team)):
    g.set(team[x].name)
    Label(root, text = str(x+1)+ordinals[x%10]+' '*(4-len(str(x)))+g.get()+4*' '+str(team[x].strength)).grid(row = x%(len(team)//3+1), column = 2*(x//(len(team)//3+1)))

#black boxes to separate teams

for x in range(0, len(team)):
    Label(root, text = '    ', bg = 'Black').grid(row = x%(len(team)//3+1),
                                                  column = 2*(x//(len(team)//3+1))+1)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is my first Stack Overflow question, so If I need to update my question or do something differently, please tell me

Comment: Don't comment on your own question if no one has asked anything, just edit it, also this is too big, split it into smaller parts that are not working

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter doesn't redraw when the variable that was used to set it's text elements change. Instead, you need to use a **Variable Class**. If you want to do something other than update the label (like to reorder the list), you need to use the `trace` method.

Source:
https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm

Comment: What sort of function would I have to write for the callback in trace?

Comment: I wouldn't actually use it in this case. I would just reorder your list in whatever function you use to change the stringvars.

Comment: What happens if I change the team's name? It still won't show up?

Comment: I made an excel spreadsheet to contain the team data; then loaded it onto my program using pandas. This way I can edit the data in the spreadsheet, then load the final version into python to reorder the list. Not sure if this is the most concise method, but it works for me.